# Usecase of EOS for DApps

Tags: nodeos, cleos, eosjs, dapp

I have watched several tutorials for building DApps with EOS.

But, All they did in tutorials was deploying smart contract and storing data in the tables.

1. What is the point of doing that?(storing data can be done with normal database.)
2. Each action returns transaction id and what do we do with it?
3. What is overall workflow of DApp?

Can someone please give me explanation?

Answer (score 1):

Its not about the storing of data, but about the authentification and authorization of that data. A blockchain allows you to know that a specific person performed a specific transaction.

Transaction IDs are useful for looking back into the history to understand what happened in the past. You can copy and paste a transaction ID into a block explorer such as bloks.io in order to see what happened in a particular transaction at some point in the past.

As for the overwall workflow of a dApp, that question is very broad, can you ask a new question and try to be more specific?